# Average of elements in a list in the second column

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, average

I have a 2 dimensional list of file names and file sizes and I'm trying to find the average of all of the elements in the second column and after searching for about 2 hours can't find any help.

Here is my list:

```
input: print fileArr

output: [[['david.ppt'], [56437456]], [['terry.dmg'], [54485656]], [['mike.doc'], [6593543]], [['randy.docx'], [5968434]], [['rick.exe'], [4538565]], [['chris.txt'], [2569437]], [['sarah.txt'], [458667]], [['fred.png'], [54966]], [['terry.dat'], [4596]], [['flyer.jpg'], [4305]]]
```

I have tried multiple possible solutions with no avail.

Comment: Why do you wrap the values in an additional list?

Comment: It was my understanding that it is in a 2 dimensional list. If you're referring the three beginning brackets ("[[[") it's just the way I copied it from IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = [[['david.ppt'], [56437456]], [['terry.dmg'], [54485656]], [['mike.doc'], [6593543]], [['randy.docx'], [5968434]], [['rick.exe'], [4538565]], [['chris.txt'], [2569437]], [['sarah.txt'], [458667]], [['fred.png'], [54966]], [['terry.dat'], [4596]], [['flyer.jpg'], [4305]]]
vals = [i[-1][0] for i in s]
print(sum(vals)/float(len(vals)))
```

Comment: @EdselNorwood glad to help!

Answer (score 5):

This might do it:

```
fileArr = [[['david.ppt'], [56437456]], [['terry.dmg'], [54485656]], [['mike.doc'], [6593543]], [['randy.docx'], [5968434]], [['rick.exe'], [4538565]], [['chris.txt'], [2569437]], [['sarah.txt'], [458667]], [['fred.png'], [54966]], [['terry.dat'], [4596]], [['flyer.jpg'], [4305]]]

average = sum(second[0] for first, second in fileArr) // len(fileArr)
print(average)
```

The key observation, as Willem commented, is that each of your items are wrapped in an extra, extraneous, list. So the first pair isn't what one might expect:

```
['david.ppt', 56437456],
```

But instead is a pair of single-element lists:

```
[['david.ppt'], [56437456]],
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is rather weird that you wrap the values (as string, which is already weird) in another list.

A declarative approach is to use `numpy`:

```
from numpy import array

array(fileArr)[:, 1, 0].astype(int).mean()
```

For your sample data, this will give:

```
>>> array(fileArr)[:, 1, 0].astype(int).mean()
13111562.5
```

Numpy is a way to construct multidimensional arrays. By using `array(..)` we load the data into a numpy array. Then we use slicing `[:,1,0]` we obtain for every row the second item and then for that list the first element. Next we use `astype(int)` to convert the items into integers, and then we call `.mean()` to calculate the average over that array of integers.

Comment: Its just the way i copied it.

Comment: `numpy` is always useful, but isn't it an overkill in that situation?

Comment: @KyrSt: well numpy has several advantages: it is more efficient for large amounts of data, furthermore it is declarative (code explaints itself), and furthermore it takes cornercases into account (like `NaN`s).

Comment: Yes, yes it is all of those and more. My only concern is that it may be confusing to a less experienced programmer (that I guess is more likely to find this question). I am not saying this is not a correct/helpful answer I just wanted to pinpoint the previous fact to maybe help somebody coming by this to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, get all the second elements from each inner list:

```
all_sizes = [x for _, x in fileArr] # we use _ as a variable name for the first element of each inner list.
                                    # _ as a name usually indicates it won't be used
```

now, all you have to do is find the average

```
print sum(all_sizes) / float(len(all_sizes))
```